# is there way to exclude an entire folder(s) when publishing a site?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, publishing

i want to have test pages in a folder called "tests" and be able to run the pages during debug but when i publish the application it excludes those files. Im using Asp. Net 3.5, Windows Server 2008, and c# Vs 2010

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could either exclude it from the project, which isn't really ideal, or you could use a post-build event script that would remove the folder you don't want published. Alternatively, you could try adding something like this to your project file:

```
  <itemgroup>
    <excludefrombuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\obj\**\*.*"/>
    <excludefrombuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\Properties\**\*.*"/>
    <excludefrombuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\*.csproj*"/>
    <excludefrombuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\*.resx"/>
    <excludefrombuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\*.Publish.xml"/>
  </itemgroup>
```

Take a look here for more information on this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx

Comment: Visual studio should add a feature for this. Eclipse has this feature.

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying this "The element ItemGroup in namespace 'link to msbuild 2003' has invalid child element "ExcludeFromPackageFiles". Any ideas?